# How do you preserve cell formatting when removing a hyperlink with Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Removing a hyperlink from a cell also removes formatting.

```
Selection.Hyperlinks.Delete
```

Is there a way to preserve the formatting, or do I need to reapply it after removing the hyperlink?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution was to call

```
Range.ClearHyperlinks
```

instead of

```
Range.Hyperlinks.Delete
```

the former clears the hyperlinks and leaves the formatting intact. Reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194741.aspx

Comment: Is `ClearHyperlinks` defined in Excel 2003 ?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a little strange as well... not sure if this will be acceptable for you or not. Try this:

```
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Address = ""
```

This pretty much acts like there is no hyperlink. The only difference is that your cursor changes to a hand instead of the default plus sign, but you can still click it like any other cells.

Comment: Ben, I'll play around with this to see if it will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Hope it works out for you. Let me know if you come up with any as well. This was an interesting question.

Comment: In this case I actually needed to delete the hyperlink. I like your idea though, and will add it to my bag of tricks. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions give problems if you work with merged cells. 
This works arround that problem

```
data = Selection.value
Selection.Value = ""                            'this removes the hyperlink
Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone 'remove the hyperlink underlining
With ActiveCell.Font                            'replace hyperlink blue with black
   .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
   .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.Value = data
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to prevent the formatting from getting zapped. The workaround I came up with was to copy the cell before removing the hyperlink and then pasting the format back to the cell after I deleted the hyperlink:

```
' copy cell to remote location to "remember" formatting
ActiveCell.Copy Sheets("Templates").Range("a1")

' remove hyperlink
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Delete

' reapply formatting
Sheets("Templates").Range("A1").Copy
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Show me a better way of doing this and I'll accept your response as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveCell.Style = "Normal"
```

With other words: 
You reapply the style that should be there. Whereas "Normal" can be changed in the name of either cellstyle present in Excell. If you want your own style to be applied with this way, add it to the cellstyles list.

If you want to go a step further. You can take the cellstyle already there, catch it in a string and reapply.

```
Dim sStyleName as String
sStyleName = ActiveCell.Style 'Capture the current cellstyle
ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Delete  'Remove the hyperlink
ActiveCell.Style = sStylename 'Reapply the cellstyle used before
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each cll In Selection
    cll_val = cll.Value
    cll.ClearContents
    cll.Value = cll_val
    With cll.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    End With
Next
```

This also helps when you don't want to copy paste information to/from another location. Have't tried this on merged cells, but I guess this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim temp As Variant
temp = (RangeObject).Interior.Color
(RangeObject).Hyperlinks.Delete
(RangeObject).Interior.Color = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply the hyperlink to a shape that is transparent and overlays the cell in which you desire a hyperlink.

The drawback here is that the cursor changes with a mouseover when not linked. And the shape can be moved by the end user and deleted as well.